# how do you associate a class file with a file in your library in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, embed

I'm trying to start using a Flash IDE called FlashDevelop which uses no .FLA editor which is what I'm used to.  I've found how to embed files from the /lib folder into a project but am unsure how to, as I've done before, associate a embedded file (for example a .jpg) with a .as file to provide it with instructions on how to act.  Below is the code representing my attempts to figure it out, thanks in advance for any help.

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    [Frame(factoryClass="Preloader")] //This references an auto generated preloader which I haven't touched
    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        [Embed(source="../lib/index.jpg")]
        public var logo:Class; //I'm attempting to connect the image in the above line to my logo.as file, all that's in there is an empty constructor and a simple update method that moves the image to the right
        public var pic:logo;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            // entry point
            pic:logo = new logo();
            addChild(pic);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
        }

        private function update(e:Event):void 
        {
            pic.update();
        }



    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply move your index.jpg embed and instantiation into *logo.as*. (Also, if you stick to naming your classes with capital letters it can help avoid confusion between classes and variables, so for example I would call it *Logo.as* instead.) Then your main class only needs to add a `new Logo()` and *Logo.as* will take care of creating the actual image.

Edit: Also, make sure you're not doing this by accident:

```
pic:Logo = new Logo();
```

That should just be:

```
pic = new Logo();
```

Comment: Doing so causes the errors to disappear but the image isn't rendering on the screen.  Is there something that I have to do in the Logo.as file to render the image?

Comment: Ah, are you adding the image as a child in Logo.as as well as adding the `new Logo()` as a child in Main? Sorry, I wasn't very clear on that in my answer.

Comment: Could you clarify? Should I just have the embed lines in Logo.as, or in both Main.as and Logo.as?

Comment: You only need to embed it once, and it's easier to just have it in Logo.as. By embedding it, it's like adding a graphic to your fla library with whatever class name you give it (eg. `private var imageClass:Class`), so you need to make a `new imageClass()` and add it as a child to Logo, then make a `new Logo()` and add that as a child to Main.